# How can I get rid of the "Windows Boot Manager" showing up when I only have one version of Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot-manager

I installed Windows 7 over a Windows XP installation (formatting my partition in the process).  Now, when I boot, I get the "Windows Boot Manager" screen, asking me to choose between "Earlier Version of Windows" and "Windows 7."  Choosing "Earlier Version of Windows" doesn't work (not that I'd want it to anyway), so how can I get rid of this screen altogether?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While Stanley's method works, it's only a workaround. [Here's a guide how to actually delete the entry.](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2010/05/how-to-remove-earlier-version-of-windows-in-windows-7-bootloader-with-bcdedit-command-line-utility/)
I have one thing to add (in case you mess something up): Before you use the "bcedit /delete" command, use "bcedit /export" to backup your current Boot Manager config.

Comment: Ahh... I did not know how to get rid of it permanently. :) +1 for my thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend a GUI tool if you're paranoid about the command prompt - try EasyBCD.

Comment: weird, `bcdedit` isn't recognized as a command...  May have to try EasyBCD...

Comment: Hmmm, using Console2, I'm not able to see that command from any shell, but it works fine with a non-wrapped shell.  Thanks!

Comment: I think the link is broken. You should post your answer instead of linking.

Answer (score 3):

1. Right Click "My Computer"
2. Click Advanced
3. Click Startup and Recovery
4. Choose Default Operating System and Uncheck "Time To Display Operating Systems"

Answer (score 3):

Go to the "Run" prompt and type "msconfig" (without double quotes)
In the next window, go to the **Boot** tab and check that there is only one option. Remove the unnecessary options.
This should solve the problem.
If it doesn't, take a peep into c:\boot.ini. **However, take a backup of the file first in a safe location.**
Use this [Microsoft URL](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7repair/thread/a8ece38a-2de8-4931-9068-d86aeb4e4da4) for more help and info

Comment: MSConfig only shows the one Windows 7 option.  I don't have a C:\boot.ini (I do have a D:\boot.ini, but I think that's just leftover from XP)